# web service call from IE is working but its not working in chrome and mozilla

Tags: web-services, browser

i am calling web-service using this code:

```
function CallService() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://devpc4:5566/Service1.asmx/GetItems",
dataType: "json",
data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnError
    });
}
```

OnSuccess function:

```
function OnSuccess(data, status) {
alert("success");

    alert(data.d);
        alert("success1");
    var ponse = '{"TableNo":"2"}';

    alert(ponse.TableNo);

}
```

OnError:

```
function OnError(request, status, error) {


    alert(status);
}
```

it gives me output in IE but i am not getting output in chrome and mozolla.
thanx for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding these three headers you can get your output

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Answer (score 1):

got the solution using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) its working. 
But i have to add some more headers like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Max-Age
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

now its working in mozilla and chrome. thanx guys.